# eliminate line in stacked bar ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

this graph is made by ggplots but I don't know how to eliminate the lines between the stacked bars (e.g. I want to combine two pink bars into one).

[image]

Comment: are we supposed to magically extract your code from that image?

Comment: `color = NA` to your `geom` will get rid of all black lines. If that's what you want, we're done. Otherwise we'll need your code and probably some data too.

Comment: I second both comments. Please read (1) [how do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), (2) [How to create a MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as well as (3) [how to provide a minimal reproducible example in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example#answer-5963610). I.e., provide input data, the expected output, what lines of code you tried and in what they failed.

Comment: Ok, let me post the code.

Answer (score 2):

Build the sum of the values for the two pink bars for each sample:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
# create sample data based on one of your last posts:
set.seed(1)
otumat = matrix(sample(1:100, 100, replace = TRUE), nrow = 10, ncol = 10)
rownames(otumat) <- paste0("OTU", 1:nrow(otumat))
colnames(otumat) <- paste0("Sample", 1:ncol(otumat))
df <- melt(otumat)
df <- rbind(df, df[which(df$Var1=="OTU10"), ])

# Build two plots - original one + aggregated one:
lst <- list(aes(x=Var2, y=value, fill=Var1), 
            geom_bar(stat="identity", color="black"), 
            labs(x=NULL, y=NULL))
p1 <- ggplot(df) + lst
p2 <- ggplot(aggregate(value~Var1+Var2, df, sum)) + lst
gridExtra::grid.arrange(p1, p2)
```

[image]